# JavaScript arrays - efficiently calculate average in given intervals

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, average

I have two arrays, one of them represents data, and the other one - intervals. Both are sorted and their start and end values match. I go through nested for loops to calculate the average of data points in a given interval. As a result, I end up with one data value for each interval. For smaller size arrays, < 100-500 length, these linear loops do the work, however, this approach becomes an issue with several thousand data points. Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Please see a simplified code below with a link to JSfiddle at the end

```js
var TimelineArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
 DataArray = [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 19, 22, 24, 25, 30, 31, 38, 39, 51, 56, 57, 58, 59, 64, 74, 76, 89, 91, 92, 94, 98, 100],
 DataArrayA = [];

for (i = 0; i < TimelineArray.length-1; i++) {
 var dataPointsInGivenTimeInterval = [];
 for (j = 0; j < DataArray.length; j++) {
  if (DataArray[j] > TimelineArray[i] && DataArray[j] <= TimelineArray[i+1]) {
   dataPointsInGivenTimeInterval.push(DataArray[j]);
  }
 };
 if (dataPointsInGivenTimeInterval.length == 0) {
  DataArrayA.push(null);
 }
 else {
  var sumOfdataPoints = null;
  for (k = 0; k < dataPointsInGivenTimeInterval.length; k++) {
   sumOfdataPoints += dataPointsInGivenTimeInterval[k];
  }
  var avg = sumOfdataPoints / dataPointsInGivenTimeInterval.length;
  DataArrayA.push(avg);
 }
} // end for

console.log(TimelineArray);
console.log(DataArrayA);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

The console output is

```
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
[4.75, 15, 25.25, 36, null, 56.2, 64, 75, 89, 95]
```

Here is the code at JSfiddle - [calculating average values for given intervals](https://jsfiddle.net/ef4vkfzs/3/)

Comment: i have a simple solution for getting averages from arrays if that helps? and a complex one that adds such functions to the Math Object?

Comment: https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/Math.Extensions use `Math.average([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])` results in `49.09090909090909`

Comment: Is the TimelineArray always have the same interval between the elements (in this case 10)?

Comment: The interval is always the same, however, the number of data points for each interval would vary - from 0 (e.g. null value in one interval in the example) to any number. This is why I keep a temporary array dataPointsInGivenTimeInterval to store and then calculate the average from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the arrays are sorted, you can do it linearly with respect to the size of the timeline and data:

```js
var timeline = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    data = [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 19, 22, 24, 25, 30, 31, 38, 39, 51, 56, 57, 58, 59, 64, 74, 76, 89, 91, 92, 94, 98, 100];
var averages = new Array(timeline.length - 1);
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < timeline.length; i++) {
  var sum = 0,
      items = 0;
  for (; data[j] <= timeline[i]; j++) {
    sum += data[j];
    ++items;
  }
  if(i) averages[i-1] = sum / items;
}
console.log(averages);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to re-scan `DataArray` from the beginning on each iteration.

```js
var TimelineArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
var DataArray = [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 19, 22, 24, 25, 30, 31, 38, 39, 51, 56, 57, 58, 59, 64, 74, 76, 89, 91, 92, 94, 98, 100];

var res = [], pos = 0;

TimelineArray.forEach(function(v, i) {
  for(var sum = 0, n = 0; DataArray[pos] <= v; n++) {
    sum += DataArray[pos++];
  }
  i && res.push(n ? sum / n : null);
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I like the idea of not scanning the entire data array from the beginning on each iteration. What about the end part? I believe the same idea could be applied to the end tag of that same data array. Once the data value becomes greater than the right edge of the given interval in the loop, then it is obvious that the rest of the data array would be greater too. So they can be ignored too.

Comment: Note that @Oriol beat me by a good 10 minutes with a very similar solution that's not re-scanning from the beginning either. ^^ Not sure to understand your idea on the end part. It would not apply to your example data set since both arrays end at 100, would it?

Comment: OK, actually it is already there, I just missed it, in @Oriol's code the nested loop's condition does what I was mentioning (; data[j] <= timeline[i]; j++). Your code does the same. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll be any faster, but here's a crack at it in a different way:

```js
var TimelineArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
DataArray = [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 19, 22, 24, 25, 30, 31, 38, 39, 51, 56, 57, 58, 59, 64, 74, 76, 89, 91, 92, 94, 98, 100],
DataArrayA = [];
  
function avg(arr){
  if(arr!= null && arr.length > 0)
    return arr.reduce(function(a, b){ return a+b;}, 0) / arr.length;
  return null;
}
for(var i = 0; i < TimelineArray.length-1; i++){
  var interval = [TimelineArray[i], TimelineArray[i+1]];
  var data = DataArray.filter(function(a){ return a > interval[0] && a <= interval[1]});
  DataArrayA.push(avg(data));
}

console.log(DataArrayA);
```

edit 1: removed a loop.